# Libre Office writer gives me only a tiny icon

Tags: libreoffice

I have used writer daily for many months, but since yesterday it does not come up. I get a very small double icon for my file and all it does is allow me to close.

I messed with settings to no avail. I tried advice on the internet. One said to trash Libre Office prior to reinstalling and now I can't restore it. I tried reinstalling with a sudo and got the error that Office writer cannot be found. I tell everybody how much I like Linux but now it vexes me. Help please

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice`

Comment: Sometimes clearing LO configuration by `rm -rf ~/.config/libreoffice/` helps. What is your Ubuntu version? How LO was installed?

Answer (score 2):

The Libreoffice window can nowadays be resized to a ridiculously small size:

[image: Minimal sized LO window]

(note within green mark).

Simply resize the window: move the mouse cursor over it until it changes to a resize cursor, and drag to resize the window. The new size will be remembered.

[image: enlarging the LO window]

If you already deleted LibreOffice, then install it again with the command

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

or using the software center.