# LO Macro editor alway opens with a collapsed window

Tags: libreoffice

I am having a problem with LibreOffice Macro. Whenever I open the macro editor (from Calc, Writer, or any other), the macro editor window appears collapsed, like a very thin and short vertical line close to the left-top corner. I have to find and enlarge it to see the editor. If I close the editor and the calling app, launch it again, and open the macro editor, it shows up collapsed window again (never saves the last window sizes). This has been occurring for a while, for both, Ububtu version and LO version (I reckon about 6 to 9 months or even more).

I use Ubuntu 23.10, and the LO version is 7.6.4.1 (X86_64), OS LINUX 6.5, UI render: default, VLC: gtk3, locale en_US,Ubuntu package version: 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.2[image: The collapsed window is the short vertical line on the top left,close to the top left corner of the Calc window.]

Comment: not entirely clear what you tried but did it include [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377813/libre-office-writer-gives-me-only-a-tiny-icon)? Also [this one](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/small-icons-for-writer-documents/22622)

Comment: It is similar, the first link. The "icon" is in fact a collapsed window. In my case it shows as a very thin vertical line (see image of the first post, with the vertical line at the top-left corner of Calc). If I close the app and lef the BasicIDE open the "icon" turns like that in the link. But in my case ii is only with the macro editor, I not only desinstalled and reinstalled, but I also changed the name of the folder "user" in /.config/Libreoffice/4. That means that I started a fresh LibreOffice, but the same problem occurs (even the message of 1st use of LibreOffice appeared).

Comment: perhaps raise a ticket with LO support community as in this link https://ask.libreoffice.org/tags/c/english/5/macro which refers to macros specifically.